# facebook comment box display issue in website

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter, google-chrome, facebook-comments

I need to display Facebook comment option in website, sometime randomly display only in google chrome.But I need to display both Mozilla and  Google Chrome browsers.
I use this script:

```
  (function(d, s, id) 
{ 
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return; 
js = d.createElement(s); 
js.id = id; 
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId="+<?php echo $fb_app_id; ?>; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); 
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='';
 arser=document.getElementById(id);
 //parser.innerHTML='<div style="padding-left:5px; min-height:500px" class="fb-comments" data-href="'+newUrl+'" data-num-posts="20" data-width="380"></div>'; FB.XFBML.parse(parser); }
(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script></div>
```

Comment: i use this script:    Script:

     <div id="fb-root"> 
<script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '<?php echo $fb_app_id; ?>', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

Comment: (function(d, s, id) {  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId="+<?php echo $fb_app_id; ?>;  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='';   arser=document.getElementById(id);    //parser.innerHTML='<div style="padding-left:5px; min-height:500px" class="fb-comments" data-href="'+newUrl+'" data-num-posts="20" data-width="380"></div>';    FB.XFBML.parse(parser);    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script></div>

Comment: Issues:

In the above div tag, iframe not append in div tag.
While load facebook comment option page,  not call directly below url

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?api_key=817201138337986&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D40%23cb%3Df3a4508c6a9eea8%26domain%3Ddemo.cogzideltemplates.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fdemo.cogzideltemplates.com%252Ff3bd56420a198f%26relation%3Dparent.parent&href=http%3A%2F%2Fdemo.cogzideltemplates.com%2Fclient%2Fbindou%2Frooms%2F66&locale=en_US&numposts=10&sdk=joey&width=470
Could you give idea for this issue.